# Template Specialization Not Working with Derived Class

Tags: c++, templates

I'm doing template specialization for one of my classes, and I'm experiencing something unexpected..

This is my code:

```
class Base {};
class Derived : public Base {};

template<typename T>
void doSomething(T t) { cout << "All Types!" << endl; }

template<>
void doSomething(Base b) { cout << "Base!" << endl; }

int main() {
    Derived d;
    doSomething(d);       //prints "All Types!"

    return 0;
}
```

I have a template function doSomething(T) that accepts parameters of any type.. except for type Base class.

So I specialized the doSomething  template for parameter of type Base,, so it does something different.

When I pass a Derived class to doSomething, however, it prints "All Types!", while I expected it to print "Base!", because Derived class is essentially a Base class too.

Why does this specialization not work for Derived?

Any way to make it work?

Thanks

[>>> Test Link <<<](http://ideone.com/8a2RmO)

**UPDATE:**

Someone mentioned overriding instead of template specializing.. but how would I override function in this case?

If I instead had:

```
template<typename T>
void doSomething(T t) { cout << "All Types!" << endl; }

void doSomething(Base b) { cout << "Base!" << endl; }
```

then doSomething(d) would also print "All Types!" instead of "Base!",, because Derived2 object would simply be considered as Type template parameter

Comment: Step 1: stop specializing functions.  Override instead.  Overriding and specialization interact in annoying ways.  Then think about the overrides.

Comment: Do you really intend to slice your Derived objects?

Comment: @n.m I don't think that matters in my case.. I just want the function overloading/specialization to work..

Comment: Does it actually work for Base object itself?

Comment: @Yakk Override or overload? What is step 2? Which step is profit?

Comment: @Ashalynd Yes, it works for Base [LINK](http://ideone.com/8a2RmO)

Comment: Object slicing can hardly be considered working.

Comment: @dyp override, sigh.  There is no profit until we can see out of the veil of tears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you `doSomething(Derived)` you cause your `template` to be speculatively instantiated with `T=Derived`.

This works (no SFINAE), so it becomes a candidate.

`doSomething(Base)` is either not considered, or is a worse match than `doSomething(Derived)`.

Specialization simply changes the implementation of that one instantiation of `doSomething`.  It does not change how it is considered at all.

Overriding adds another override, which then competes with your `template` version using the usual rules.

There are a few ways we can route calls to `doSomething` that are passed a `Base` or any class derived from base to a single implementation.  I'll show 2.

First, tag dispatching.

```
namespace aux {
  template<class T> void doSomething( std::true_type /* is Base */, T t ) {
    // T is a class derived from Base
  }
  template<class T> void doSomething( std::false_type /* is Base */, T t ) {
    // T is not class derived from Base
  }
}
template<class T> void doSomething( T t ) {
  aux::doSomething( std::is_base_of< Base, T >{}, std::forward<T>(t) );
}
```

(replace `{}` with `()`, and drop `std::forward<T>` in C++03)

Here, we explicitly route derived classes of `Base` to a different override.

Another approach would be to SFINAE exclude the `template` from consideration, and have an override:

```
template<class T>
typename std::enable_if< !std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value >::type
doSomething( T t ) { /* blah */ }

void doSomething( Base b ) { /* foo */ }
```

now the `template` version is excluded from consideration by SFINAE, and the override is used instead.

I find tag dispatching to be more clean.

Comment: Wow great solution.. Btw is there a reason why you omitted "void" in front of doSomething(T t) declaration in the second solution?

Comment: Hmmm I think we had that discussion before -- is the term *override* appropriate for that the Standard calls *overload*, especially considering the new "keyword" `override`? Is it commonly used in that sense? (Am I too pedantic?) I'm confused

Comment: @user2436815 the `enable_if` provides the `void` if it passes SFINAE.

Answer (score 3):

You might solve it with std::enable_if:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

class Base {};
class Derived1 : public Base {};
class Derived2 : public Derived1 {};

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if< ! std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value>::type
doSomething(const T&) { std::cout << "All Types!" << std::endl; }

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value>::type
doSomething(const T&) { std::cout << "Base or Derived!" << std::endl; }

int main() {
    // All Types!
    doSomething(1);
    // Base or Derived!
    doSomething(Base());
    doSomething(Derived1());
    doSomething(Derived2());

    return 0;
}
```

Note: The argument is `const T&`, but having T as argument avoids the mentioned slicing, already.

Note: `typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value>::type` is the return type, which is an optional second template parameter of std::enable_if, defaulting to void.

Comment: Note that this creates two different overrides of `doSomething`, it does not specialize.

Comment: awesome solution!! Btw is there a reason why you omitted "void" in front of doSomething(const T&) declaration?

Comment: Oh,, so if the return type is bool instead of void, I can do:            "typename std::enable_if< ! std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value, bool>::type"  ?